# Most relevant papers on IR / discount rate(s) modelling in the last 5 years

Tags: interest-rates, swaps, interest-rate-swap, discounting, cross-currency-basis

As the question states, what are some relevant recent papers I, as a non-expert, should read on IR modelling, products, and mechanics (that do not involve AI/ML)?

I think my knowledge on this topic has not progressed much beyond Piterbarg's Funding beyond discounting (probably still an important paper?) and Boenkost & Schmidt's Cross currency swap valuation. So I have a lot of catching up to do.

My aim is not to become an expert on IR/FI overnight, but simply to not be completely ignorant of the latest developments.

Just to illustrate what I mean, for example the paper by [Lyashenko and Mercurio, Looking Forward to Backward Looking Rates](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Looking-Forward-to-Backward-Looking-Rates%3A-A-for-Lyashenko-Mercurio/31f6d9dbe871c0a331902da17b1447bcb9102753) seems very relevant, but is it one of the most important in the last 5 yrs? Guidance here would be appreciated.

As there isn't really a right or wrong answer to the question I'd probably hesitate to give an 'accepted' answer if there are multiple answers, but I'll of course give good answers +1.

Comment: @Alper Not really. I could of course search online and spend quite a lot of time deciding which are really important, but I am hoping that there are experts here that can guide me as I am not an IR expert.

Comment: Oh come on...here we go again. The question is a duplicate? Please explain where the duplicate question is and why it is duplicate.

Comment: I agree this is not a duplicate. There is value in a knowledgeable person filtering and ranking the fire hose of papers on this subject.

Comment: Opinion based rather than a duplicate.

Comment: That’s a valid point. Maybe it should be Community Wiki but if I make it so no one earns reputation which isn’t beneficial to this community.

Comment: @Frido it might be beneficial to describe which sub-topics you feel most lacking in and specifying what your ultimate goal is so someone can suggest a study path.

Comment: I'm too old to be polite, and right now frankly also too annoyed. Sorry. Please let's be more fluid in our thinking and attitude instead of being trigger-happy and compulsively ticking boxes. Even answers of an intelligent bot is spiced with opinion. If the purpose of this site is only to give answers that can be formulated as an equation, then it defeats its purpose. ChatGPT can give me code and equations, better than most of us can. So, let me and perhaps others sharing my incomprehension know where this site wants to go to. Based on that I'll decide whether to continue contributing or not.

Comment: @BobJansen My rant is not directed at you, just to be clear. Thanks.

Comment: For what it's worth, I agree with @Frido. I have only become recently active in this community again, but based on a few cases that I observed I also got the subjective impression that questions occasionally get closed for a very narrow interpretation of "opinion-based".

Comment: I see my question has been re-opened. I suspect by Bob, thanks for that. But I'm going to close it because it's really not efficient this way, and certainly not pleasurable. But my general question about where this site wants to go to stands, as does my rant above.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because let's just close this.

Comment: @Frido thanks for you comments here. I agree regarding the general philosphy of avoiding trigger happy closing and just try to build a general database of useful knowledge, even if its not perfectly organised and categorised. As a mod I try to encourage this such as https://quant.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1727/29443, but ultimately stack exchange is a community and with its democrayic style tends to forge its own destiny. FWIW I hope you do stick with it.

Comment: @Attack68 Thank you for your comment and thoughts. I was irked, but counted to 10 and stuck with it. After all one can only change things if one sticks with it. It might be good to start over with this question then, eg by deleting all the (heated) comments which probably onle a mod (you or Bob) can do. Cheers, frido